# C# How to sort different elements with the same method

Tags: c#, list, sorting

What in parameters should i use to sort different elements with the same method? Right now i have 4 copies of the method for the different elements.

```
public static void SortByMÄRKE()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newklädDataList.Count; i++)
        {
            int minst = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < newklädDataList.Count; j++)
            {
                if (newklädDataList[minst].märke.CompareTo(newklädDataList[j].märke) > 0)
                {
                    minst = j;
                }
            }
            if (i < minst)
            {
                Swap(minst, i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'd want your method to be generic and take a generic collection.

Comment: What type is newKladDataList? And why don't you use List<T> where T is your type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to make your method generic on the type of the items in the collection and on the type of the property you are sorting on.  Then you'd need to pass in your collection and a selector.  And the type of the item you are sorting on would have to implement `IComparable` of itself to be able to use `CompareTo`.  So something like this.

```
public static void YourSort<T,U>(this IList<T> collection, Func<T, U> selector) 
    where U : IComparable<U>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
    {
        int minst = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < collection.Count; j++)
        {
            if (selector(collection[minst]).CompareTo(selector(collection[j])) > 0)
            {
                minst = j;
            }
        }
        if (i < minst)
        {
            var temp = collection[minst];
            collection[minst] = collection[i];
            collection[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
newklädDataList.YourSourt(x => x.märke);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<T> sort(List<T> inputList)
```

would be your method header, and then you would write code that can operate fully agnostic of type. Whenever you need a new object of that type or collection of that type, you use T like this:

```
T newobj = new T();
List<T> newList = new List<T>();
```